# Converse factional string to number in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Convert a string to number in Matlab can be use `str2num` but this function does not work with fractional string. Example,

`str='[2/3 1/3]'`

`a=str2num(str)` `Error:Requires string or character array input.`
Does Matlab have built-in function to convert fractional string to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.  It works for me:

```
>> str='[2/3 1/3]';
>> str2num(str)
ans =
    0.6667    0.3333
```

Try `whos str` to check you have it typed it correctly.  It should appear as:

```
Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

str       1x9                18  char
```

Comment: Thanks - this is really weird. I have 2 Matlab Version 2013a and the 2013b and one works but one does not.